# New job: how to successfully transition from honeymoon to real world?

Tags: new-job, relationships

I just started a new job. It took the company a while to find somebody with my background, and as a result everybody is ecstatic about having me. My colleagues take me for lunch, all senior bosses are full of smiles and are happy to have me, my initial ideas and suggestions make everybody happy and I am getting lots of support.
In parallel, people keep stopping me by saying "great to have you, I have a project for you". I have enough projects for the next 12 months at least, and more are coming. Some are outside my field of expertise, but "there is only you" is the main argument used by my manager.
I am confident that I can manage with my workload, but I am worried about my relationship with my colleagues. My manager will help filtering projects, but I am worried about the moment when the hard reality will clash with my colleagues' and bosses' expectations. There is only me, but my days are not infinite.

So, my questions is: how can I transition out of this honeymoon phase without making enemies or making people angry?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Work at a steady, sustainable pace.

You have only two hands and one head, so work with your manager to determine which projects you are tackling first. Be specific with your manager that you want him to notify you ASAP if the priority and deadlines of projects change. And that he is the one who determines what projects you are working on. Re-route all requests that you work on specific projects to your manager, and let your manager know that you will be redirecting these requests to him going forward.

The more business-like you come through, the more confidence you will inspire although not everyone will be happy with you all of the time - hey, that's what happens when there is only one of you and when there are only so many office hours during the weekday. They may not always be happy with you but they will always have confidence in  you - whis is exactly what you want.

Do not put in put more overtime than you can physically take over an extended period of time.Be very careful about making promises that you can't keep or even worse, promises that you will only be able to keep with heroic, life energy draining efforts. If you can keep these two factors under control, you will not be raising unrealistic expectations or even worse, expectations that you can meet only at huge physical and mental costs to yourself.

One last piece of advice: when you are given a project, always give yourself some time to think over what is the most effective and efficient way to get it done. DO NOT rush headlong and start coding immediately - nobody wins marathons by starting with a sprint.

Comment: Excellent answer to this question.

Comment: `nobody wins marathons by starting with a sprint.` I take you don't like Scrum? Heh heh...

Answer (score 5):

Gather some intelligence about your colleagues' and managers' expectations and use that to report how much work achieving those aims might entail. If that figure is vastly beyond what you as a sole employee can do or delegate informally, raise it **early** and raise it **forcefully** if necessary. It may be that the business' conception of what's involved is wildly inaccurate, and in order to complete the work to a satisfactory standard, more resource is needed. Normally that's a hard sell, but it's clear that they already consider you the expert, so that should lend weight to your opinion. Being told that there's a very large bill incoming is preferable to a project failing because it isn't humanly possible to do the work.

> My manager will help filtering projects

Because you know you're already busy, accept *nothing* without doing your **own** planning. When someone tries to get you to do something for them, something like:

> This looks like an interesting piece of work. I have no spare time at the moment, but I'll confer with [Manager] about whether we can fit this in and get back to you.

- Reassures that you're not just fobbing off and do consider their needs to be of value
- Sets the expectation of a tangible response
- Reminds that although you're paying attention to scheduling, it isn't your call

> How can I transition out of this honeymoon phase without making enemies or making people angry?

So to try and answer your question concisely:

People become angry when they're given unexpected and negative news whose consequences cause them inconvenience. You can avoid anger and move to a more mature working relationship by *setting expectations* and delivering news which might not be the receiver's preferred state of affairs as early as possible, so that they can plan for it. **Absolutely do not** keep quiet about anything that would make a collague's life much more difficult if revealed later, rather than sooner.

Answer (score 2):

Communication is the key. Everyone shoudl know what order the projects are going to be worked on, how long is expected for each project and what support you will need from them (things like specific requirements documents, client files, logos or other graphics that need to be provided, etc.) and when you will need them.

Then as things change (and they invariably will), you notify them that something esle has taken a higher priority and psuhed their proeject back or that a prjoect is taking longer than expected and has pushed thier project back.

As you are new to the company, you need your manager to set project priorities and he may need to have all the players work this out among themselves. You do not have the specific company knowledge yet to even suggest priorities.

Everyone likes to think their peoject is the most critical. But when you have more work that you can do in the short-term a formal priority list that is shared with everyone is a must.

Answer (score -1):

Problem point:  "There is only one you"

What I'd say:  "There needs to be another person hired with my skillset or knowledge or background".

Typically, the current state will end in one of two ways:

i) The person in your role (currently you) will make everybody happy, but will not have work-life balance, and be subject to health problems and possible family complications.

ii) The person in your role will offend people by turning things down.

An alternative to asking for another hire is to have EVERYTHING routed through your manager.